# In Firestore Should user id of a user be private(secure, shouldn't be shown the other person)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am making a chat app. I'm linking two users data via uid of two persons chatting. So, in the process of accessing uid of another person I'm exposing the uid of the other person.

So, is it safe?

Or can someone hack into the system by just getting uid of another user?

Thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Database - Risks associated with exposing uid on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620723/firebase-database-risks-associated-with-exposing-uid-on-the-client-side)

Comment: What do you mean by "safe" or "hack into the system"?  Knowing a UID doesn't facilitate a hack, except if your application security allows for whatever "hack" to get private information about the user with just that string.  We have no idea if that's the case here.